I have some questions about my planet's climate and its geography
This planet's climate is the same as Earth's, only the inclination is different (25°) and the global temperature is either the same or 1°c higher. The planet is slightly larger than the Earth, 7092km in radius.
What would the climate be like on the great continent at the South Pole?


Welcome Aydan. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] particularly the [ask] section. You'll see we have a one-question-per-post policy. Each question should be posted in its own thread - and you can link them if you like, linked series of questions are enjoyed here.

One question per post, start at the top and work your way through, you'll find some questions answer themselves given information on other sections or due to the research needed to assemble a good query. You'll also need to give some information about your world's Milankovitch cycles when you want answers about long term fluctuations like ice ages.

Hello @Aydan, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Considering that your planet is so closely modeled after Earth (even the map is basically the Earth), what about Earth's antarctic climate fails to meet your needs? Remember, per the [help/on-topic], our goal is to help you build an imaginary world. We're willing to use science to help you rationalize your fictional creation, but we're not the right place to find validated scientific answers to anything. The science says, "it'd be a lot like Antarctica." So? Have I answered your question?

One more thing: The [help/dont-ask]'s "Book Rule" tells us that if an answer can be reasonably the size of a book, the question is inappropriate for SE. Considering climate questions are among the most difficult to answer and that there already are books about Antarctica's climate, your question certainly violates that expectation. Said another way, the bigger the scope of your question, the lower the detail of the answers you should expect to get - assuming the Q isn't simply closed. SE wants focused questions.

It would be hard to judge this... you're missing the AU distance from the star... the star power output... atmosphere... assuming they are all earthlike, the climate would be basically the same, with the "upper" most section possibly being temperate with seasons.  Too complex, but very interesting. I would hazard a guess as "almost the same, more wind, some seasons at the edges"
